# Aggregate sampler function for programmer express predictions

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, aggregate

Are there any SQL-standard or DBMS implementation that offers "sample aggregator" for predictably repeated columns?

I will explain, see bold text at the end.

PS: this question is about "little performance gain" in big tables, and about "semantic enhancements" in the *SQL language*, in general.

---

As typical table, we can imagine a SQL-view `v1` of some piece of data:

```
Organization   | City           |  Country | Info1 | Info2
---            | ---            | ---      | ---   | ---
LocalOrg1      | San Francisco  |  US      | 10    | 23
LocalOrg1      | San Francisco  |  US      | 2     | 24
Armarinhos Fer | São Paulo      |  BR      | 11    | 55
Armarinhos Fer | São Paulo      |  BR      | 12    | 56
```

My (programmer's) prediction is that all organizations of `v1` exists in only one city (eg. there are only one "San Francisco City Hall"). So,on basis of my prediction, the query

```
SELECT organization, city, country, 
       sum(info1) as tot1, avg(info2) as avg2, count(*) as n
FROM v1
GROUP BY organization, city, country  -- city,country predicted repeat
```

have some redundancy and some semantic limitation: 
the grouping criteria is  `organization`, there is no need to spend CPU checking `city`  and `country`. And I can say "Hey John look that query grouped by organization", because it does not make sense to say to another human   "organization, city and country" when he have the same prediction in mind. It was a SQL obligation but is not the semantic essence of the query.

Of course, the semantic may be better with `GROUP by organization, 2,3` syntax sugar, or using `max()`,

```
SELECT organization, max(city) as city, max(country) as country, 
       sum(info1) as tot1, avg(info2) as avg2, count(*) as n
FROM v1
GROUP BY organization  -- better semantic, worse performance
```

but `max()` lost time "comparing nothing" (because as I predicted there are only repeated things), and perhaps the query cost will be bigger than the first query.

Some DBMS also offer `first()` and `last()` which might be more efficient (!) then `max()`, and I guess that this is the simplest solution today: use some kind of `first()` function optimize performance and semantic, in basis of my prediction that city and country repeats when grouping by organization.

But no matter if the sample of a repeated column comes from first or last sampled row. The first/last can be also an internal optimization choice, so, the real need in this context is a kind of `aggsample()` function:

```
SELECT organization, 
       aggsample(city), aggsample(country) -- better semantic and perfornace
       sum(info1) as tot1, avg(info2) as avg2, count(*) as n
FROM v1
GROUP BY organization  -- better performance
```

So, putting in this detailed context: **Are there are any *SQL language variation* where this kind of function (`aggsample`) was defined?**

---

EDITED after comments and some homework...

### NOTES

Candidates and limitations:

- [PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). Seems to address the similar problem, but not solves the use in usual GROUP BY summarizations.
- [MySQL's `ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), as suggested by @AndriyM. Seems perfect (!), but I never used... Will try later, install mysql and do some tests.

Similar discussions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8373384/287948
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/36134657/287948
- ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/20347763/287948

#### Trying

```
CREATE TABLE v1 (
  Organization text,  City text,
  Country text, Info1  int, Info2 int
);
INSERT INTO v1 VALUES 
 ('LocalOrg1', 'San Francisco', ' US', '10  ', '23'),
 ('LocalOrg1', 'San Francisco', ' US', '2   ', '24'),
 ('Armarinhos Fer', 'São Paulo', ' BR', '11  ', '55'),
 ('Armarinhos Fer', 'São Paulo', ' BR', '12  ', '56');
```

Extrange, PostgreSQL offer as valid syntax "DISTINCT ON + GROUP BY",

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (organization) organization, city, country, 
       sum(info1) as tot1, avg(info2) as avg2, count(*) as n
FROM v1
GROUP BY organization, city, country
```

but not works better (worst performance) and is not valid the reduction ou grouping with only `GROUP BY organization`.

... no other test.

PS: the only valid syntax (and result) with `DISTINCT ON` of postgresql is

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (organization) organization, City, Country, 
    sum(Info1) OVER w AS tot1,
    avg(info2) OVER w AS avg2,
    count(*)   OVER w as n
FROM v1
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY organization);
```

as we see, ugly syntax, and with worst performance.

Comment: You seem to be talking about [MySQL GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: That said, I'm not sure if it makes sense at all to pick a SQL variation (and, consequently, a SQL product) based on one specific feature – especially taking into account that you aren't actually speaking about a real performance problem, you are just making guesses. They look sound, I give you that, but the issue may not necessarily be big enough to worry about it prematurely. Perhaps some measurements/comparisons could clear that up.

Comment: Thanks @AndriyM, your clue about MySQL was perfect (see my edit), the MySQL's  `ANY_VALUE()`  seems my `aggsample()`.  About "pick a SQL variation", my aim is *not* a SQL product choice, is only to check "sucess experiences"  in this feature, and perhaps  *to show a reference model* to other SQL user-community (ex. PostgreSQL users).

Comment: I wonder if `TABLESAMPLE` is what you are looking for: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tsm-system-rows.html

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, is a clue, but no... It is used for *statistical sampling*  purposes, and act in whole row.  Eg. `TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (50)`  is like `WHERE random()<0.5;`, but with "randomness at the page level instead of the tuple level" [1](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @AndriyM, the link to [this new features in **MySQL** 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) led me to the **`ANY_VALUE()` function**, that is exactly the "aggsample" of my question!

- Performance conclusion: the use of `ANY_VALUE()` function represents some gain  in performance, demonstrated by thousands of real world use cases of MySQL databases, and by the decision to preserve this advantage in nowadays versions of MySQL, that bring us with this new function.
- Usability (friendliness) conclusion: `ANY VALUE()` makes  possible semantic gain (takeoff the non-grouping columns) in the `GROUP BY` clause.
- Philosophical  conclusion: it is way to programmer express his/her predictions about repeated values.

so, `ANY VALUE()` is a good recommendation for any other SQL language!

---

### NOTES

To test you need MySQL 5.7+, and check `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode` or set mode to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

The query works fine,

```
SELECT organization, any_value(city) AS city, any_value(country) as country,
       sum(info1) as tot1, avg(info2) as avg2, count(*) as n 
FROM v1 GROUP BY organization;
```

Another interesting behaviour in MySQL is let user in a friendly mode, where `any_value()` is not necessary — so, is also possible to avoid "AS name" boring syntax. In this special (non-standard) mode, the following query have the same behaviour,

```
SELECT organization, city, country,
       sum(info1) as tot1, avg(info2) as avg2, count(*) as n 
FROM v1 GROUP BY organization;
```

Comment: to install mysql5.7 in ubuntu ``wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb\n
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.3.2-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb\n
sudo apt-get update\n
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7``

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge: you wouldn't have this problem if you normalized your database properly. Therefore, the problem should have been solved at the design stage and you wouldn't need to invent semantically ambiguous aggregate functions to work around it.

If the combination of `Organization`, `Info1`, and `Info2` is guaranteed to be unique (which I'm pretty sure is not the case), then these attributes form a composite candidate key. Subsequently, your relation is not in the 2NF, as `City` and `Country` are only functionally dependent on a subset of the candidate key (`Organization`), and need to be in a different relation.

If the combination of `Organization`, `Info1`, and `Info2` is *not* guaranteed to be unique, then this relation  is completely unnormalized (i.e. is not indeed a relation) and you need to start your design from scratch.